# get the axis to be the same in the pairs function

Tags: r, scatter-plot

```
pairs(iris[,1:4])
```

[image]

will produce a set of scatter plots relating the 4 variables to each other.
It will scale each axis differently depending on the range of each variable.

Is there a way that I can instead set the axes to be the same for every plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `xlim` and `ylim` arguments into `pairs()`:

```
pairs(iris[,1:4], xlim=c(0,8), ylim=c(0,8))
```

Comment: It would have been nice if pairs calculated the range for you. But this works for me!